# How make a Distinct correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, distinct

i would like make a Distinct correct for this query in SQL server 2014

```
select DISTINCT IntrnalKey,   CatName, QName, QString 
from OUQR inner join
     OQCN
     on QCategory = CategoryId
```

i had the error - Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

is there is better ways please help me

Comment: `ntext` is obsolete.  Fix your data model so the data is stored using `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: you might be able to get away with CAST(Qstring as nvarchar(max)) as 'Qstring'  on whichever fields are ntext, in your SQL that is

Answer (score 1):

To use an ntext column in `SELECT DISTINCT` you need to first cast it to another data type. My go-to is `SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Field AS NVARCHAR(MAX)`.